# Various numbers in data

Tags: sql

If one has various degrees of measurement data that is also rather fuzzy, for example:

```
100mg    
30ml    
0.5mg    
12 mg    
.03g
```

How would it be possible to grab the measurement data?

I've looked into `PATINDEX(%[0-9]&) and NUMERIC`

I feel like my code should be tending towards something along the lines of:

```
... LIKE '%'+NUMERIC(5,2)+'%'
```

Comment: You may be better off separating the number and the unit into separate columns - or storing the number in base units (e.g. `G`, `L`) rather than keeping the number _and_ unit in a single string column.

Comment: @DStanley at this moment in time I'm not too fussed about the unit, rather  the numerical value and keeping its accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a function that described [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

And use it for your column:

```
select dbo.udf_GetNumeric(column) 
from table
```

Comment: This works perfectly but it doesn't account for the decimal point.

Comment: @BrandonWhite Please change the regular expression in two places from `'%[^0-9]%'` to `'%[^0-9.,]%'`